# How to I clear the state of the container instance that hangs on "waiting"

Tags: azure

I have a docker image that I have been running for couple of weeks so far. I’ve  decided to push the image to Azure ACR. After creating the container instance, the container instance status shows “running”  but when I go into containers (setting), status shows “waiting”.
-I stop and restart the container Instance-same result
-I deleted the container and pushed again with different name (tag)-same result
Any ideas?

Comment: Check the containers logs to identify any issues during startup.

Answer (score 0):

This state means that might be the init container still running or or the container is backing off due to a crash loop.

So, you need to check the logs to understand the situation. and it might be a resource issue

you might also redeploy the container instance again with a different name

You can get more info with the Microsoft [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-state#containers)